# Should I use password hash as secret key in HMAC?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

I am trying to build a password reset / forgotten password link. The link would be sent by email to the user. So far, I'm taking this approach:

1. Generate token using `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));`
2. Store a **hash** of this token in a db table
3. Store an expiry time for it.

The url would be `/reset-password/{$email address}/{$token}`

I'd like to add an HMAC to the url. If I do so, can I use that user's password hash (**Edit: - hash created using `password_hash()` in PHP5.5**) as the secret key safely? e.g.

```php
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $url_without_hmac, $password_hash);
```

so the new url would be `/reset-password/{$email_address}/{$token}/{$hmac}`

and the hmac would enable us to verify that the url is genuine without having a globally stored secret key. Does this seem a safe approach, use of email to send the link notwithstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't do this.

A HMAC key is the same thing as an encryption key, meaning that it MUST be completely random and unpredictable. Passwords hashes don't have that property, and could also be of insufficient length.

What's worse, if you did that, you'd be exposing a second (and possibly easier to exploit) attack vector for your users' passwords - an attacker would be able to determine a user's password *hash* via brute-force, allowing them to later perform the same attack *locally* for the password itself.

And finally, even if these flaws didn't exist, you wouldn't really be adding any meaningful safeguards with this idea. You're just over-engineering it.

Comment: Could you explain your second para a little? How would someone be able to brute-force the key given the HMAC? I was under the (possibly wrong) impression that the secret key in an HMAC is secure.

Comment: I'm not saying that the key in question isn't a secret ... a brute-force attack means blindly guessing all possible combinations. The problem is that if an attacker *somehow* manages to succeed with such an attack, they will also have the password hash, which is otherwise much more expensive to do get (in terms of computational power).

Comment: It seems that the attack you're suggesting could be applied to any HMAC secret key, and in my specific case the attacker would have to guess the complete url (guessing the email address, token and hmac). 

So, alternatively I could use a per-user random string as the key, stored in the database with the token hash.

Comment: Yes, the attack is ineffective and could be applied against any other secret ... it's the increased potential damage that I'm warning you against. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest it, others might disagree, however, I would consider that a breach of security; hashes are not 100% secure so potentially giving out a user passwords unnecessarily would be dangerous. It would be a far safer alternative (and really not that much work) to set a temporary token separately and store it to your database with an expiry time